# C++ WinAPI - GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo always fails by invalid handle (Returns 0)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm writing a simple program to output the correct (and current) width and height of the console in chars/lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &csbiInfo);
    cout << csbiInfo.dwSize.X;
    cout << csbiInfo.srWindow.Bottom - csbiInfo.srWindow.Top;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

However, while GetStdHandle doesn't return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo fails (returning 0), with error code 0x6 (invalid handle)

I've also tried using GetConsoleWindow(); in place of GetStdHandle to no avail.

I'm using windows 10 and VS2017. I get the feeling I might be either in over my head, or pushing to do something too system-specific.

Thanks in advance for any solutions/alternatives.

Comment: What happens if you use `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` instead of the input handle?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles

Comment: "Initially, STDIN is a handle to the console's input buffer, and STDOUT and STDERR are handles of the console's active screen buffer"

Comment: *"Input"* and *"screen buffer"* have no overlap. If you want to know, how many characters you can **output** to a line in the screen buffer, you're going to have to use an output handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STD_INPUT_HANDLE is usually connected to the terminal keyboard.
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE and STD_ERROR_HANDLE are usually used as console.So let's say the STD_INPUT_HANDLE Can't be identified as a "console handle" by "GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()". You can use "STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE" to get the console handle.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <Windows.h>
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
      CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo;
      GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbiInfo);
      cout << csbiInfo.dwSize.X;
      cout << csbiInfo.srWindow.Bottom - csbiInfo.srWindow.Top;
      system("PAUSE");
  }
```

Comment: What about not getting a handle? and use the one you already have. In other words this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

While Drake Wu answer was a good hint... Oh what am I talking about, the question was the same good hint. Drake's answer is no answer.

I was sufferring with this problem for days and have the solution and reason.

The problem is MSDN poor documentation of this function, GetConsoleBufferInfo. And no one cares about consoles anymore to be discussing it else where. Android is the in thing and it gives consoles and terminals the middle finger.

MSDN states that the handle must be a console out handle. It doesnt tell you how to get that handle.

```
HANDLE h_out = CreateFile("CONOUT$",GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
```

OR

```
HANDLE h_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```

Then it says the handle must have GENERIC_READ access rights. What the hell!!! Isnt console input the one that should have GENERIC_READ access rights??? Oh! They can have both access rights.

```
HANDLE h_out = CreateFile("CONOUT$",GENERIC_WRITE|GENERIC_READ,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
```

Assigning to STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE does similar. This is how to make GetConsoleBufferInfo accept your handle.

But good, great!!! that one console handle can have both access rights. Instead of using two handles I will use one!!! Just like posix.

```
 char buf[90];
HANDLE fhandle = CreateFile("CONOUT$",GENERIC_WRITE|GENERIC_READ,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
WriteFile(fhandle,"I am not accepting input from this handle",90,NULL,0);

// ReadFile fails
ReadFile(fhandle,buf,90,NULL,0);
```

Well that sucks. So why does CONOUT have GENERIC_READ access? You know what? Screw opening terminal with CreateFile.

PS: Microsoft console api is more trouble than its worth. And the posix functions _open, _read, _write you should stick to; Unless you need or desire to do certain things like cleverly changing colour of text and background. A big problem with console api is it fails upon large request read.

```
Read/WriteFile(handle,buf,65000 bytes!,0,0)  // fails
```

However

```
_read/_write(fd,buf,100000 more bytes) // doesnt fail, plus it has less parameters
```

PS^2 I have bee designing utility libraries since I began learning Cpp. Such is my file library currently supporting Win32 and Linux. I now want to offer them to the wider public if they may be of use as they have helped with my problems. my email address is d.master51@yahoo.com